Software update kills video card output
I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.  The latest offering from Software Updater has a problem.  Whenever I allow it to install the latest update, and after the restart, GRUB comes up normally, (I have both Ubuntu and Windows 10 to choose from), and when I try to start Ubuntu, my video card's output is effectively shut off.  All I get is a black screen and an error message from my hardware telling me to check my video cable.
